# Recording audio .. cut off

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, getusermedia

Reluctantly, I am asking you guys here to help me overcome my brain freeze. I am recording audio but I have a problem with not being able to get the recorded audio without half of it missing.

```
recAudioInput = recAudioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream); 
recorder= recAudioContext.createScriptProcessor(theBufferSize, 2, 2); // (or 1,1, no difference)
recAudioInput.connect(recorder);
recorder.connect(recAudioContext.destination);
```

Recording for let's say 5 seconds and speaking 1 2 3 4 5 gives me about 200K of data containing 1 2 3 ... I will have to wait (and continue to record) the same amount of time (in this case 5 seconds) to get the rest. Quite frankly, that doesn't seem right.

But I don't see the error. Shouldn't the inputbuffer return a total of about 400K of data per channel (44.1 * (16/8) * 5) after 5 seconds?

Thanks for your help.

Michaela

Comment: Ok. It was my fault. The sizes are correct. I made an error in the WAV conversion leading to the described problems. Stupid me. I consider the case closed. Thanks.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question and close it with your error if possible for posterity, please.

Comment: Answered it. Didn't find a way to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry. It was my own stupid mistake. I made a miscalculation of the expected wav file length which in turn lead to a shortened wav file missing a few seconds.